# How to create a good glass reflection with Principled BSDF

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

So I'm part way through a fun small project, and I would like some advice about how to improve the glass material at the far end of the scene on the two doors.

In the ref photo the reflection is sharp, but you can also see inside the fridge or whatever it is.

I'm aware there's still a lot of things left to do in this scene, improve lighting, finish up materials but I'd like to address this glass shader.

PS - Any other tips appreciated, I'm a fairly novice user! I do 3D in spare time because I just love it.

[image: render]
[image: ref]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly, for this I would just use a mix of a Transmission shader and a Glossy shader. But if you want to use a Principled shader:

- Set the base color to #FFFFFF, so you don't have darkened glass. (Unless you *want* darkened glass, of course.)
- Set the Transmission to 1 and the Transmission Roughness to 0.
- Set the Specular to 0, you don't need it.
- Set the Metallic to 0.2 or so. This will control how strong the reflections are; you should probably adjust it to fit your specific light source.
- Set the IOR to 1.0, since you're making a cabinet—refraction will just slow things down.

Here's a quick test render:

[image: quick glass test]
<sub>(I got the HDR from [here](https://hdrihaven.com/hdri.php?hdri=sunny_vondelpark).)</sub>

As you can see, the icosphere is a reflection, the cube is not.

Comment: a Mix of Glossy and Transmission Shaders will not take care of fresnel therefor you SHOULD use a principled bsdf shader

Comment: @GolgorieHaus Unless you mix them with a fresnel node. For objects where refraction doesn't play a big role, it's generally a reasonable approximation (and a good optimization) to replace refraction with straight transparency

Comment: @GolgorieHaus Thanks, didn't think of that! You're talking about Fresnel with the reflection, right? Reflecting more as you get more edge-on?

Comment: I would just like to add in case someone misses the tag at the bottom of the question, this only works in the Cycles Render Engine.